# grouping id with string value instead integer SQL GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

On Google I just found group by sum (integer value). How can I group by a string value?  For the table:

```
No   Place    Car 
---  ------   --------
1    NY       VRM1
1    BT       VLI
2    NY       GAR
3    GT       GAR
```

How can I group by 'No'?  I tried:

```
SELECT No, place, Car 
FROM  APPEL
GROUP BY No, Place, Car
```

But it didn't work.

I want to have a table like this

```
No   Place    Car 
---  ------   --------
1    NY,BT    VRM1,VLI
2    NY       GAR
3    GT       GAR
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL SERVER Query result in CSV format is possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880021/sql-server-query-result-in-csv-format-is-possible). or this http://stackoverflow.com/q/446783/27535

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-- Sample data
with T (No,   Place,    Car) as
(
select 1,    'NY',       'VRM1' union all
select 1,    'BT',       'VLI' union all
select 2,    'NY',       'GAR' union all
select 3,    'GT',       'GAR'
)

-- The query
select
  T.No,
  stuff((select ','+T2.Place
         from T as T2 
         where T.No = T2.No
         for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as Place,
  stuff((select ','+T2.Car
         from T as T2 
         where T.No = T2.No
         for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as Car
from T
group by T.No
```